# Tkinter can't use image for icon despite it working else where

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to create an icon image for a window in my program but I keep on receiving this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
  File "F:\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "f:\CompSciProject\Master File.py", line 167, in view
    ViewyPagey()
  File "f:\CompSciProject\Master File.py", line 1388, in ViewyPagey
    ViewPage.wm_iconphoto(False, icon)
  File "F:\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2183, in wm_iconphoto
    self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, *args)
_tkinter.TclError: can't use "pyimage5" as iconphoto: not a photo image
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
def ViewyPagey():

  ViewPage=tkinter.Tk()
  ViewPage.title("View Database")
  ViewPage.resizable(False,False)
  ViewPage.configure(bg="#0073CF")

  frame1=tkinter.Frame(ViewPage, bg="#0073CF")
  frame1.grid(column=0, row=0)

  dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
  file_name = os.path.join(dir_path, "images\\nhslogo5.png")
  icon=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_name))
  ViewPage.wm_iconphoto(False, icon)
```

The use of DIR is to get around an issue I've been getting but if I insert `print(file_name)` after it is defined, then it prints out the directory that it's meant to, so that's not the issue.

Furthermore, what is strange is that I use this exact same code for a different window and it works without a single error, so I'm not really sure why it isn't working. That code is as follows:

```
def ViewyPageyAdmin():
  ViewPageAdmin=tkinter.Tk()
  ViewPageAdmin.title("View Database")
  ViewPageAdmin.resizable(False,False)
  ViewPageAdmin.geometry("1300x710")
  ViewPageAdmin.configure(bg="#0073CF")

  ViewPageCanvas=tkinter.Canvas(ViewPageAdmin, bg="#0073CF", bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
  ViewPageFrame=tkinter.Frame(ViewPageCanvas, bg="#0073CF")

  frame1=tkinter.Frame(ViewPageFrame, bg="#0073CF")
  frame1.grid(column=0, row=0)

  dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
  file_name = os.path.join(dir_path, "images\\nhslogo5.png")
  icon=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_name))
  ViewPageAdmin.wm_iconphoto(False, icon)
```

So I'm not sure why this doesn't work, anyone have any ideas? Thanks :)

Comment: It may be because there are more than one instance of `Tk()` in your first example.  Try `icon=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file_name), master=ViewPage)`.

Comment: @acw1668 thank you very much, that has resolved the issue. Would you be able to explain what exactly has happened here since I'd like to understand to avoid it in the future. Thank you!

Comment: Each instance of `Tk()` has its own scope.  It the `master` option is not specified when creating an instance of `PhotoImage()`, it will be the first instance of `Tk()` by default.  So for the first example, the instance of `PhotoImage()` is not created in the scope of `ViewPage` and so using it in the scope of `ViewPage` will be problem.